# Razer Kraken with Pi 2

Tags: pi-2

Does the Razer Kraken work with a Pi 2? Is the sound card compatible or not?

[Razer Kraken page](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-audio/razer-kraken-usb)

Comment: I suggest if you have the device to plug it into the Pi and see what happens. I suspect the drivers required to make the sound over USB work are not available for the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

No.  From  the "TECH SPECS" section of the web page:

> - PC / Mac with USB port
> - Windows® 10 / Windows® 8 / Windows® 7 / Mac OS X (v10.8 - 10.11)
> - At least 100MB of free hard disk space

The last two points in particular imply this device requires a lot of software, which has **exactly zero chance** of being usable in any way, on any model of Pi, using any operating system.

Since the connector is USB and not a normal 3.5mm stereo jack, it could not be used as a normal set of headphones with the Pi's built-in sound system either.

Comment: how to know which microphone suit pi 2 driver? thanks

Comment: There's no microphone jack on any of the Pi's so you will have to get a USB "soundcard".  They're an inch or so long, usually cost $5-20 USD and have two 3.5mm jacks, one out (green) one in (pink) like traditional soundcard ports.  *Most* of those should work out of the box without requiring any driver installation, since USB sound is standardized.  But a device that requires 100 MB of free space almost certainly uses some non-standard proprietary software, which you will not be able to install in this context.